# Can you custom name a job?

Tags: powershell

Using powershell and i have several items that i'm triggering using start-job. 
now i would like to display some statuses of the job, but the problem is that the autogenerated name Job1-x  is not very helpful if you have many jobs going.

How can i add a custom name to a job so that i can indicate the status when the jobs have finished.

```powershell
    Start-Job -ScriptBlock { tfsbuild start /collection:"xxx" /builddefinition:"xxx1" }
    Start-Job -ScriptBlock { tfsbuild start /collection:"xxx"  /builddefinition:"xxx2" }

    Do 
    {              
        $meJobStatesRunning = Get-Job -State Running 
        Start-Sleep -s 1   #give time for job to process before checking.
    } While ($meJobStatesRunning -notlike '')

    Get-Job | foreach {  if ($_.state -eq "Completed") {write-host -f green $_.name $_.state } else {write-host -f red $_.name $_.state } }
```

Comment: never mind.. i see you just need to add the -Name to the start-job command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, use the `-Name` parameter.

```powershell
Start-Job -Name MyName -ScriptBlock { tfsbuild start /collection:"xxx" /builddefinition:"xxx1" }
```

[Start-Job Documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849698.aspx)